# File transactions and Kernel32.Dll

Tags: c#, transactions

I would like to implement MoveFileTransacted method from kernel32.dll. After I will move file I must invoke database row commit. How to implement MoveFileTransacted in TransactionScope?

I found something like this:

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool MoveFileTransacted([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lpExistingFileName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lpNewFileName,
            MoveFileFlags dwFlags, IntPtr transaction);
```

**UPDATE**

```
        private void Test()
        {
            var sF = @"C:\" + Guid.NewGuid();

            var dF = @"C:\NewFile";

            Console.WriteLine("Store");

            try
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(sf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    fs.Write(Content, 0, Content.Length);
                }

                using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    IntPtr transaction = Manager.GetTransactionFromDTC();
                    if (transaction != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        if (Manager.MoveFileTransacted(
                            sF, dF, Manager.MoveFileFlags.MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH, transaction))
                        {
                            Commit();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                        }
                        Manager.CloseHandle(transaction);
                    }
                    ts.Complete();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Is the MoveFileTransacted signature correct? I found something like this: codeproject.com/Articles/17421/WebControls but I have exception: The current transaction context associated with the thread is not a valid handle to a transaction object. ERROR_CURRENT_TRANSACTION_NOT_VALID

Comment: You want to implement it or to use it?, if what you want is just to use it, mapping it with PInvoke like this will do the job

Comment: Microsoft [no longer recommends the use of transactional NTFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh802690); I'd think twice before building an application around this. There's been some [efforts](http://improve.dk/utilizing-transactional-ntfs-through-dotnet/) to wrap the functionality in .NET, but banking on this to remain available seems risky. Consider if something like [`FILESTREAM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server) can serve your needs instead.

Comment: I want to use it. Is there any solution to get execption from MoveFileTransacted? I would file to know why this method return false.

Comment: That's a much easier question. `throw new Win32Exception()` if the function returns `false` (it takes care of calling `GetLastError` and producing a human-readable message.)

Comment: ok thanks, I forgot about it